# how do you lazy load images into listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I can not find a good answer for setting an imageview inside a listview

I am using asynctask to get the images.

I am using an arrayadapter for my list view.

In my array adapter in getView i set the id of the view to my object id.

As the fetched images return from the server I do the following to update the view with the image.

```
private void populateListImage(Bitmap bitmap, long id) {
    View view = m_findByRegionList.findViewById((int) id);
    if (view != null) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        viewHolder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

1st problem:
This is really slow.

2nd problem:
setting the view id to my object id must be wrong

Answer (score 1):

I used this, works perfectly fine
[load images](http://evancharlton.com/thoughts/lazy-loading-images-in-a-listview)

Comment: I would like to understand why my solution is slow.  Is it correct to get hold of the view in this way?  I suspect not as all view operations should be done in getView.  If this is the case.  What is the best practice for getting the object from the the adapter and setting a property?